# Facing issue while fetching latest data's in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing the issue while fetching the latest data from MongoDB. every 3 hours I am pushing the data to the MongoDB when I fetch the latest data's I am facing an issue.

Here is the Schema

```
var abc = new Schema({
    item_name: String,
    uploadedDate: String, //"6-29-2019"
    date : Date
});
```

Fetch the latest data's
req.body.uploadedDate = "7-2-2019" String

```
router.post('/todayList', (req, res, next) => {
  abc.find({ "uploadedDate": { "$eq": req.body.uploadedDate} })
    .then(product => {
      let final = funct.duplicate(product, 'item_name'); here i am filter duplicate object 
      var result = [];
       final.forEach(comp => {
        abc.find({item_name": comp.item_name, "uploadedDate": { "$eq": 
    req.body.uploadedDate} }) // here i am fetching the latest uploaded data based on the item_name and pushing to the 'result'
        .sort({"date":-1})
        .limit(1)
        .exec((err, docs) => { 
          console.log(docs); //i am getting the latest data here
          result.push(docs);
         });
       })
       //but here the value of 'result' is empty array
      res.status(200).json({
        data: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

I am not able to find why it's giving an empty array. please help me with this

Comment: Could you post an example of the item you're trying to fetch as it sits inside of mongo and the actual query that you're sendinngn (`req.body.uploadedDate`). If the data truly exists I'm guessing its missing a leading `0`: `7-02-2019`.  This is why it's useful to use more specific types, ie parse `uploadedDate` into a date object annd then filter on mongo `date`, this gives you greater assurance that data is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the for loop is asynchronous.
Therefore, the response is sent with an empty result, before the queries in the for loop are done running.

You should make the code wait for the queries to finish running before sending the response.

```
router.post('/todayList', (req, res, next) => {
  abc
    .find({ uploadedDate: { $eq: req.body.uploadedDate } })
    .then(product => {
      let final = funct.duplicate(product, 'item_name')
      var promises = []
      final.forEach((err, documents) => {
        promises.push(
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            abc
              .find({ item_name: comp.item_name, uploadedDate: { $eq: req.body.uploadedDate } })
              .sort({ date: -1 })
              .limit(1)
              .exec((err, docs) => {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                resolve(docs)
              })
          })
        )
      })

      Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
          data: result
        })
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      })
    })
})
```